# Is this concept for a reference counting memory manager for use with maps good?

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a memory management system to deal with pointers being stored in maps.

```
struct refmanager{ //since this class is only for inheritance
//and not for polymorphism their does not need to be a virtual destructor
int count;
refmanager():count(0){}
```

};

The first idea I had was to inherit the above struct into classes I am going to insert into maps as pointers.

```
    template <class P> void ref(P ptr)
{
    ptr->count+=1;
    cout<<"increasing ref count\n";
}

template <class P> void deref(P ptr)
{
    ptr->count-=1;
    cout<<"decreasing ref count\n";
    if (ptr->count==0)
        delete ptr;
}
```

Than I was going to use the above template functions to increase and decrease the reference count. To make the system automatic I was going to use the template functions below as replacements for the normal map methods (note this is not complete and the clear map method was written for my test case and is not generic).

```
  template <class M, class K, class V> void mapinsert(M &map, K key, V value)
{
    ref(value);
    map.insert(pair<K, V>(key, value));
}


template <class T> void clearmap(T input)
{
    deref(input[1]);
    input.clear();
}
```

From preliminary testing this idea works. But I don't have the knowledge to know if this will lead to possible disaster later. Can someone with more experience please let me know if this memory management concept is any good and if not when, where and why will it fail?

Comment: Have you studied `std::shared_ptr<T>` from the standard library? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

Comment: I did look into shared_ptr but to my knowledge it only works if you enable c++11 or have a c++11 compliant compiler. Since I am writing this code for public development I am sticking to the previous standard because many compilers are not yet completely c++11 compliant.

Comment: @ZacharyKraus: have you considered `boost::shared_ptr` then ? It works in C++03. `boost::shared_ptr` is thread-safe, your version is not; also `boost::shared_ptr` comes with `boost::weak_ptr` (weak references are a must in ref-counting), offers support for custom deleters, etc... (ie, it's full featured)

Comment: Ill check that out. But, just out of curiosity what makes the above code not thread safe?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos I tested shared_ptr. I really liked it a lot. Since I will be using very large maps in my code I did speed testing for the above memory manager and shared_ptr. The memory manager for large maps (1 million items and larger) is about 20% faster and uses a lot less memory. The result was kind of a shame since shared_ptr is so much easier than developing a custom memory manager.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is requesting a critique of supposedly working code. Sounds like a task for Code Review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only look at the space release of reference object (`delete ptr`),  but where is the allocation?

You must ensure every reference objects are allocated **in heap, not in stack**.

`value` in `ref(value);` is a pointer? Because `value` is the template defined type, it may be NOT a pointer.

Comment: The allocation is done before inserting the pointer into the map. How do you ensure value in the template function is a pointer?

Comment: like this: template <class M, class K, class V> void mapinsert(M &map, K key, V* value). value's type is 'V*', not 'V'.

Comment: When I started testing this feature I actually wasn't sure how this would work but after reading up extensively on templates and doing my own testing. It actually doesn't matter whether you label it V or V*. Here's the source for that statement: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257589/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part. Additionally since the compiler compiles templates in 2 passes rather than one. On the second pass when its adding the type it will test to make sure the pointer arithmetic is valid and if the pointer contains a variable called count.

Comment: If the passed in variable is not a pointer or the pointer doesn't contain the variable count, the Program will not compile. I actually tried to compile invalid types because I was worried about type safety. Also If you try and delete a ptr for memory on the stack you'll get an error like "kmap(21247) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fbdd3c03a18: pointer being freed was not allocated" during the run. I just wanted to add this information in here in case anybody wanted to use this implementation. Shoot maybe I answered my own question LOL. If I did ill move this information to the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I cant put code in comments. Anyway this was in response to Charlies answer. By the way he is right and the method above is doable but is not the safest method. Below is a safer method.

you can produce a refmanger class with this code:

```
class refmanager{
private:
    int count;
public:
    refmanager():count(0){}
    virtual ~refmanager() {}
    void ref(refmanager* ptr)
    {
        ptr->count+=1;
    }
    void deref(refmanager* ptr)
    {
        ptr->count-=1;
        if (ptr->count==0)
            delete ptr;
    }
};
```

The refmanager class can be inherited by classes which need to have their pointers reference managed.

The code below will now only compile when V and T are objects which contain the ref and deref methods with the correct format. In other words you are ensuring the code will not crash unexpectedly in the middle of running it.

```
template <class M, class K, class V> void mapinsert(M &map, K key, V value)
{
    value->ref(value);
    map.insert(pair<K, V>(key, value));
}

template <class T> void clearmap(T input)
{
    input[1]->deref(input[1]);
    input.clear();
}
```